# New Contributor Indicator! Can we make it less intrusive?

Tags: feature-request, comments, new-contributor-indicator

I am aware about this new feature discussed here: *[Come Take a Look at our New Contributor Indicator!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314287/come-take-a-look-at-our-new-contributor-indicator?cb=1)*, but I find it somehow intrusive in some cases, especially for comments. I get the banner for each comment I will add to the question which is a bit bothersome.

[image]

I think we should show the banner only for the first comment and avoid the same information to be shown again and again. Also a comment can be a reply to someone else, so it's not necessarily a direct comment to the new user.

<sup>PS: I didn't write this to debate/discuss about the feature itself <strike>even if I don't like it</strike> (it's already done in meta.exchange). I simply don't like how it's intrusive especially in the comment section.</sup>

Comment: Gotta admit, it makes an obvious barrier to trying to help new users, especially for any curator-type feedback.  The chances of the poster accepting the feedback positively is extremely low.

Comment: Do we actually need that at all? I feel like attending a basic traffic learning course, after driving without an accident for 30 years now. There are really some feckin' bloomers coming up here. It's just like _Yield_.

Comment: So... It's never about the poster, except if the user is a new contributor?.... Nice to know...

Comment: @Patrice Well, how do you react seeing that _Learner_ or similar signs on a car in traffic? (for me personally I am trying to give em tough lessons whenever I spot them ;-) )

Comment: Man panta, I hate your name on my cell lol.  When I see learner on the highway I react differently. Which means I react based on the driver. Afaik, in Stack, you shouldn't act based on the poster.... So I feel this notice is weird....

Comment: @Patrice _"I hate your name on my cell lol ..."_ Why so? I am absolutely cool ;-)

Comment: Oh you are cool and I think back to my Greek roots Everytime I see you. You're just tough to ping on an English only keyboard, with no easy c&p lol

Comment: @Patrice Yeah, that's much intentional, for making it hard to ping me ;-). Lessons, ya know.

Comment: Counter proposal: I think we should show the banner only for the first **zero** comments. Do people really have a hard time seeing the new contributor banner under the user profile so this is also necessary? For me that is about as easy to miss as a bright flashing light that's shining directly into my eyes, carried by someone shouting on a megaphone.

Comment: Look, just because someone is new to SO, does not mean that they are new to asking questions.  That's something they've been doing their whole life.  If they cannot formulate a question correctly then they should not be asking here.  Same goes for existing users with several k rep that still manage to ask horrible questions.

Comment: @JK.: Very few people ask questions, write titles, etc *competently*. And the skill of asking questions conversationally, one-on-one, is somewhat different and certainly far less demanding than the skill of asking a generally useful SO question in text.

Comment: **PLEASE** be nice, and remember who read the COC and don't show them this ever again!

Comment: (shoudl this be on [meta.se] instead?)

Comment: You mean this is not related to the Dark Brotherhood, or a new faction of Saruman's Orcs? Just in case, I will  give them a quest.

Comment: I am [Drag and Drop](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6560478/drag-and-drop), a Speaker f̶o̶r̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶D̶a̶r̶k̶ ̶B̶r̶o̶t̶h̶e̶r̶h̶o̶o̶d̶ On SO. 
And you, you are a k̶i̶l̶l̶e̶r̶ New Contributor. A taker of l̶i̶f̶e̶ vote. 
A harvester of s̶o̶u̶l̶s̶ Reputation. Your work, your deathcraft, pleases the N̶i̶g̶h̶t̶ ̶M̶o̶t̶h̶e̶r̶ SO Community. 
And so, I come to you with an offering. An opportunity... to join our rather unique family.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314517/260198

Comment: Why askers are called contributors, can anybody please kindly explain?

Comment: @SergeyA no only askers, because you can be called a contributor if you answer too ... so they decided to use a neutral name, you will contribute by asking or answering

Comment: The "new contributor" indicators scream "use kid gloves" and do not strike me as being very professional.  It's even styled with a baby blue color.  It's very annoying.

Comment: I get that people have strong feelings about the feature. I won't share my opinion of it here. Nearly every answer and comment on this question doesn't address the actual question and the OP's suggestion of displaying once per comment thread.  I think it's worth discussing that and leaving the overall feature discussion to the existing questions that deal with it generally - otherwise the general comments here are orphaned from those discussions, and the noise-to-signal here makes this question's real discussion opaque.

Comment: Sorry, but this is exactly what is needed after years and years of hostility towards new users that has gotten StackExchange a very poor reputation.  I'm just glad that the guys in charge are starting to realize how big a problem it is and deploy countermeasures of similar magnitude!

Comment: @MasonWheeler I don't care about the feature ... need or not, it's intrusive and we don't want it for each comment we post. It's not about the feature, it's something neutral for me and it's intrusive

Comment: @TemaniAfif As they say on the Internet, "this is why we can't have nice things."  This has been a long time in coming, and I'm sorry if you're feeling caught up in something where you weren't a part of the problem, but the problem is very real.

Comment: @MasonWheeler Imaging stack overflow is adding an information in a strange language that you don't understand. Do you want this information to be present everywhere? I don't think so ... My question here is not about the feature, the content, the CoC, etc. There is a banner that shows when you add a comment, I got it for the first comment and it should be enough. There is no need to add it for each comment. I am not discussing the need or not of the feature, the banner could contain the weather of today, it's the same for me : "no need to show it multiple time"

Answer (score 87):

Here's a quick rule for your favourite adblocker to make the element as unobtrusive as it can possibly be:

```
##.new-contributor-indicator
```

Or using a userstyles plugin:

```css
.new-contributor-indicator{
    display:none;
}
```

Or a userscript:

```js
$('<style type="text/css">.new-contributor-indicator {display: none;}</style>')
    .appendTo($('head'));
```

That'll completely remove the banner from the answer field and the user information block on the question.

Comment: You can also do it with a userscript - `var style = document.createElement("style"); style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(".new-contributor-indicator {display: none !important;}")); document.head.appendChild(style);`

Comment: @Dukeling Or, more tersely: `document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('style')).textContent = ".new-contributor-indicator {display: none !important;}"` ;)

Comment: Or with CSS: `.new-contributor-indicator{display:none;}` // Seriously, meta discussion is not just for the OP, it's for other people too. "It's possible to workaround this with an userscript" is not an answer to "this feature is terrible, let's remove it"

Comment: @user202729: Workarounds to revert to old functionality are perfectly acceptable meta answers.

Comment: It's a shame it doesn't also send "do not want!" feedback to the site.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I think they get plenty of that via Meta...

Comment: @Cerbrus I have seen in some cases (myself included) the desire to see it under the user card but not on the comment and answer boxes; in that case, I use this CSS for my user styles plugin: `#post-editor .new-contributor-indicator, form[id^="add-comment-"] .new-contributor-indicator { display: none; }`

Answer (score 68):

Is that not a bit too much in our face to have 3 rather rude injunctions to "do as the man said", on the same page, on every new comer post? It seems that there is a suspicion that the intent of people wanting to help is bad!

[image]

Comment: no freehand circles? :(

Comment: Those circles are terriby squary looking, too thick, and extremely regular. Your freehand leaves a lot to be desired. Are _you_ a new contributor by chance?

Comment: Is this a new suggestion on how the banner should look? That way they would get a lot more attention and I am sure that would increase the quality of posts massively

Comment: @yivi Hey, he might be a new contributor, be nice! Or I'll call the CoC police.

Comment: @Lundin: Do you _want_ to get CoCblocked?

Comment: Can we get these red borders on the site as well? I feel like it draws the needed attention to the matter.

Comment: The user icon though...

Comment: @TrooperZ user icon has 4 fingers too many.

Answer (score -15):

I for one don't mind those reminders at all. There isn't any reason anyone needs to be mean to a new or existing user. Yes, people can ask some pretty horrible questions that make you question the efficacy of the education system, but a snarky response to those questions will not net anything and silence or a polite reply wouldn't also get you.

Personally, I find it very easy to want to reply with sarcastic comments to bad questions and I'm sure I have actually done so in the past. It's a good stress release! However, I've noticed since they've started stressing being nice I'll stop and think if I actually need to post a comment on this question. Many times, I don't and just move on.

Further, I'm not sure how many of you use the other Stack Exchange sites, but many of those communities are very welcoming and warm. It makes you care more about that community and in turn its rules.

Change is always tough and it can be so much fun to mock someone when they seem deserving, but not doing so isn't really taking away from your community, it's making it better. I'm sure eventually the reminders won't need to be so in our face, but I would imagine you'll get used to them pretty dang quick!

Comment: well, I was sure this question will be turned to talk about the feature but I don't care about this feature even if I don't like it, it's here but it's very intrusive ... usefull or not, I don't think we need to have it for each comment we add. Let's consider it as a simple information, no one want to see it all the time.

Comment: this is a test comment to see if my second comment will show the helping hand

Comment: @TemaniAfif oh wow. Yes it shows up for every comment

Comment: I actually like this answer.  Yep, soon the helping hand will be like a vacuum cleaner left out in the lounge room. People won't realise they're stepping over it.