# The "New Contributor" indicator is senseless

Tags: discussion, design, new-contributor-indicator

This "New Contributor" marker is senseless in my opinion. While it might seem to be a good idea at first glance, the low score and badges of the user tag immediately catch the eye and show that the user is a newbie with all implications.

While this detail as a single measure might seem irrelevant, I would prefer to not overload the site with such markers and gadgets, since every useless or redundant piece/tag/item harms the clarity of the site (minimalistic approach)

Just my opinion...

Comment: There is perhaps a useful distinction between a user who is new and one who has already asked several bad (possibly deleted) questions (and thus keeps reputation ~0 and no badges)

Comment: [Strongly related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372877/7296893) (if you read less intrusive = gone, it's a dupe)

Comment: If you interpret the flag as 'answer or down/close/delete vote, but never comment' then it's useful: you will never be flagged, blogged of tuttered as 'unwelcoming to new.......users', (they mean 'new accounts', but never say that).

Answer (score -4):

My understanding is that as per the updated community guidelines - the indicator is there to remind people that new users might not be aware of the etiquette and features of Stack Overflow - and so the indicator is the remind people to ***be gentle and polite*** in correcting them or guiding them to use the site correctly.

Comment: Yes, the intention is quite clear, this was not exactly the point. But thank you.

Comment: The issue here, I think, is that we are supposed to be gentle and polite with *everyone*. Pointing out that someone is a newb, without any specific reason to thereby treat them *differently*, is not useful.

Comment: @RobertColumbia - right, but if statistically it can be shown that people tend to treat newbies with less respect than others, then a targeted reminder is warranted.