# Why is the "xxx is a new contributor" warning reminded in the answer box?

Tags: discussion, answers, new-users, new-contributor-indicator

I understand that some new users may find some curt or "please post your code" *comments* daunting, snarky, whatever, and all things considered, this isn't a bad thing to remind users that the person is new when commenting their post.

But on *answers* ?

```
xxxx is a new contributor. Be nice, and check out our Code of Conduct.
```

Answers contain technical information. It's just not acceptable to use comment-like language, and they're not only targeted to the new user posting a question, but to help improving the knowledge database of the site.

- comments are directed to the OP to help clarifying the question
- answers are directed to the *community* and the OP

So I don't see why the "Be nice, and check out our Code of Conduct." is there, and only for new contributors posts. Either it's there (it's implicit, and answers tone should be neutral anyway) or it isn't, regardless of the OP being a new contributor or not.

Am I missing something?

Comment: maybe because *new contributor* sometimes use the answer section to add comments? so this message is for them probably.

Comment: @TemaniAfif good thinking but ... no... We probably should replace it by "this section is for answers only", given the number of non-answers I'd dealing with in the VLQ

Comment: @TemaniAfif If that was the reasoning, new contributors should see it on every answer box, and experienced contributors should see it on nothing, That's not a logical explanation imo.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth it wasn't a *serious* comment ;) simply trying to figure out some *crazy* logic to justify all those banners ... I myself don't like them : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372877/new-contributor-indicator-can-we-make-it-less-intrusive

Comment: Ever since the "new contributor" notice, I've seen at least one case of an answer starting with "Welcome to Stack Overflow!". We really don't want this, but the current design seems to be inviting users to add noise.

Comment: @TemaniAfif: There is no logic in the illogical. I'm afraid this also applies to your question, JFF (neverthelsee, +1 for your persistent hunt for the Wumpus, aka "reason" ;-)

Comment: [Paragraph 4 of this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314296/388243) describes the same thing.

Comment: damn SO has become an extremely complex forum to understand.

Comment: @user734028 Actually, SO is not a forum.

Comment: This "Actually, SO is not a forum" statement and its upvotes further prove the point of @user6655984 and @user734028!  SO often is not a very welcoming place, and encouraging  "Welcome to Stack Overflow!" is much better than negative, condescending attitudes.  If we don't like that in otherwise good answers, we can edit it out.

Comment: @jnylen We've always been editing it out. However, editing takes time.

Comment: Driving away new users with condescending attitudes costs more time over the long run. Those users, if shown the value of this site and encouraged to stick around, will eventually become active members and moderators themselves.

Comment: I'm not into newbie bashing & I fight this as well, I don't understand your point. I very rarely saw insulting answers (other than blatant spam and non-answers like djfkshjfhsdjf). Comments, that I can understand.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I feel some snark in your profile picture. How do I flag it? ;)

Comment: @E_net4 Yep, there are [a lot of these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aanswer%20%22welcome%20to%22) actually!

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed it's not snark it's irreverence :)

Comment: @jnylen We may want to send automatic "welcome to [so]" messages, [se] may implements that later, but doing that in the comment or answer is definitely inappropriate.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed People have been doing that forever: <5% of the posts in that query are after The Welcoming. There is also, from what I've seen, a high [false positive rate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13258/3579910)

Comment: SO just put the "Be nice" text in as many places as possible where people interact. They hope it sticks even if it is annoying sometimes.Some kind of psychological trick, I guess.

Comment: @Fattie If SO goes away, its going to be because they are encouraging Eternal September instead of trying to fight it.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The "hand" is about increasing new user retention.

**TLDR**

- SO is on the decline (check Tim Post's [MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314302/are-we-creating-divisions-in-our-quest-to-make-new-users-welcome/314519#314519)).
- People are not always patient when answering questions. In fact some people can be snarky and rude. This causes people to not return to the site.
- The hand is to try and alert and remind people that we do indeed have a code of conduct and expect people to follow it. It's obvious, so anyone posting an answer won't miss it.

### Why is this on new users?

- Currently new users are being scared off the site at a rate that will kill the site.
- The site will gradually die if we don't have enough new users staying and contributing.

### Getting the attention of non-meta folk

> [... we're talking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314519/310756) to people who typically aren't causing the problems that we're trying to solve. The fact that we found a need for an indicator is a big clue there, why didn't we just write a post that said "Please be extra careful when dealing with new users?" Because the people that would most benefit from that guidance, for the most part, don't come here.

The reason the network has placed "helping?" hands at every port of communication with a new user is in an attempt to get the poster's attention. The reason this has been made so obvious, is due to the fact that the people the network are trying to communicate with, within the UX, are not regulars on Meta.

So we need to consider the UX changes are not so much for you and I (you being the reader of this post), but for the people who are not reading this post.

### The site is facing attrition that is unsustainable

The new user base that replenishes the site and forms our core user base is declining. The site will actually close down if we do not make genuine new users more welcome. It's in everyone's interest to do so (if we want the site to continue).

> #### [Our attrition rate is concerning.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314519/310756)
>
> New users just don't stick around anywhere close to how they did a few years ago. I'm not going to post the exact rates, and I'm not going to post the exact metrics that we use to consider someone 'lost' as far as likely to re-engage, but I will explain it in very simple terms.
>
> Let's say you have a bank account. Every month, $1000 goes into that
> account, and $960 goes out of it. You will never lose your income, and
> your expenses will always stay the same. Sure, you don't manage to
> save much, but year over year, it adds up, right?
>
> Well, what happens if the income isn't infinite? Let's not talk about
> money, let's talk about users, the size of the market that we serve,
> and the rate at which it grows and replenishes. If we lose even 25% of
> the users we manage to convince to interact with our sites, and the
> number that try every day keeps going up exponentially, then it's only
> a matter of time before we burn through an entire market faster than
> that market significantly replenishes itself.
>
> This is because people had really bad first experiences, and depending on how influential they are, we've lost them and possibly dozens more. It's difficult to calculate who won't try something because of this. But if we don't control this rate, we could (much sooner than later) say that the whole market uses, has tried and stopped using, or won't try our sites.
>
> That is to say, there's a hard stop where you run out of people that are (1) interested in [topic] and (2) successful using your software, and the faster you hemorrhage new users, the faster you approach that point. This is where new users don't replace long-term engaged users that tend to just naturally move on after they've done all they came here to do. This "shrink" in communities is perennial and usually healthy, as long as you eventually move to more coming in than leaving.

The network is losing users and there's concern about the site's future.

It's easy to decry "it's the crap that's killing the site". The truth of the matter is, there will be no site if its growth declines and remains that way. We need to maintain quality content and growth in constructive user base.

### Zooming out on the UX

We need to remind ourselves the majority of the main site don't read meta. Our core users who are also active on meta  are not the target for the UX changes. The target is the 1000s of people who do not read meta or come into chat

We're all on the same team. Regular meta goers, moderators and even the network powers are all on the same side. We're all just looking at it from different perspectives. We all want the site to be good and succeed. We don't want it to deteriorate and die a slow and painful death.

You (the reader) and I care for the site out of a love and respect for its content and the effort of our community. The network needs to make money and so has a financially vested interest in sustaining it. Either way it would be good to try and zoom out the focus on the UX to have a bird's-eye view of who we're targeting here.

### Conflating welcoming new users with unwelcoming old users

The old users have (by definition) proven to stick around, but it's important that our [we are for our core user base](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370993/with-a-userbase-as-diverse-as-stack-overflows-how-will-we-arrive-at-an-actiona/371015#371015). However, if we can be mindful not to conflate the arguments. Trying to improve new user retention is not necessarily mutually exclusive to trying to improve old user retention. As I see it the active meta community sometimes sees assisting (genuine) newcomers as not supporting the old timers. We need to take a breath and look after both.

Currently there are two types of problem users that the UX is addressing. The ones who are not active on meta, but put newcomers off with their behaviour (not new). The newcomers who put no effort into contributing and become abusive when asked to improve. Abusive with words or creating and disposing of accounts to continually spam the site with crappy posts. Both of these need to be dealt with.

It's important to remember, it's not the genuine newcomer who is the enemy (Even the newcomer who posts a lousy first post may end up becoming a long term contributor of quality content). It's the newcomer who doesn't care about contributing and the "old-timer" who doesn't care about the newcomers who do care. (Yeah, a lot of nested caring - I need coffee.)

## What about the regular users?

I don't have the answer. I'm pretty certain the powers that be have had a scare and they're taking new user retention seriously (I'm gleaning this from meta). I also happen to know that the powers that be are desperately trying to put in fixes to help the established user base (this is from talking to them personally).

The teams are snowed under (they told me), and the communication on the meta sites is not as through as it has been historically (my observation).  They're not consulting so much, as trying to stop the ship from sinking (my thoughts). I do know they're listening to all the feedback (my communications with them). So I know we're not being ignored, hence I am patient and trying to convey that to the community, as I am also a member of this community and understand that changes have been a long time coming. What was 6-8 weeks is feeling more like 6-8 years.

### Conclusion

For the sake of improving user retention, I suggest we work together as a community, as in the coming years, there won't be a community if we don't.

Comment: To be fair, it seems like the first-poster user base has changed a lot over 10 years (speaking from reading only, I was not actually here for 10 years). What I can say from my much shorter experience, *"We need to maintain quality content and growth in constructive user base"* seems much harder done than said. And if you realize it cannot be done, which do you give up first - maintaining growth (which would freeze things at the current technologies, potentially) or lowering quality (which could make navigating to all content much more difficult)?

Comment: but, but, I'm not _against_ this new contributor stuff (even if I'm joking about it sometimes). It's just that I feel that it has nothing to do in the "answer" section.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre if you read my post it has everything to do with the answer section, in fact anywhere contact is made with new users. As clearly there's a section of the non-meta reading community who make snide remarks - including within answers. Clear? Please advise with customary [wake up ping](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/43717992#43717992) ;)

Comment: so basically you're saying that this answer banner is to protect new contributors from ... other new contributors ? (answer appreciated, this is the "best" answer so far, because IMHO this "feature" it makes no sense in the current state)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre not to protect new contributors from new contributors. To protect new contributors from rude contributors (new or old) who either don't read meta, or obstinately ignore it (more so from the first group)

Comment: ok, so old contributors do not get to be protected then? Everyone should be protected

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre meh, the old users have (by definition) proven to stick around. But it's a good point, and one I [actively defend](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370993/with-a-userbase-as-diverse-as-stack-overflows-how-will-we-arrive-at-an-actiona/371015#371015). It's important not to conflate the arguments. Trying to improve new user retention  is not necessarily mutually exclusive to trying to improve old user retention. As I see it the community is taking assisting (genuine) newcomers as not supporting the old timers. We need to take a breath and look after both.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I've updated, can you let me know how that reads? please :D

Comment: I'm beginning to understand that a compromise must be made to avoid newcomers to leave the site because we _need_ the traffic. It's just that it could be improved message-wise for the answers.

Comment: I don't follow the logic in this answer at all. What good is this "new contributor" banner in answers if your goal is to make new users feels more welcome? Has SO ever had a problem with too much snark or other "unwelcoming" language in *answers*?

Comment: The issue is that it's _everywhere_. 3 banners on roughly 50% of the questions. And I'm not finding myself able to ignore it with time; at the bottom of my laptop screen is the answer banner and I keep catching sight of it and thinking there's an answer (ok, they don't look similar, but I just see that there's something at the bottom of the screen). How many times do we need reminding, exactly?

Comment: All of this is correct and good, but it ultimately doesn't answer the question. Putting up that new contributor indicator in the answer box doesn't really make any sense. I mean, I understand there's some contrived logic behind putting it below the user's card and the comment box, because we somehow believe that users will be less ... nasty in the comments when they see that. However, how exactly is the answer supposed to be influenced by that indicator? Be more "patient" in answering the question? What does that mean?

Comment: @Aran-Fey et al please advise if the edit has answered your concerns :)

Comment: "The site will actually close down if" wait, what? **This needs to be addressed.** We need some kind of foundation to keep a read-only archive of SO up and running if you somehow manage to "close down" a top 100 Alexa website.

Comment: @Knu yes indeed it does need to be addressed https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373158/what-does-our-long-term-community-need-what-does-our-long-term-community-need-t

Comment: well thats right, on google i often write my query with a -stackoverflow so to not get any results from here, cuz even before getting here i am thinking i dont want to read any stupid scolding people do, all i want is a techie answer to my problem and i can get it from anywhere.

Comment: @user734028 I hear you and makes me want to weep.

Comment: As someone who refers to this and other SE sites regularly, but who does not use any of the privileges I've been given here or elsewhere because of the annoying feedback when I first tried, and who - as a technical user with over 30 years experience - finds the number of non duplicate questions closed as duplicates of a merely similar question by people who clearly didn't understand it, I find it interesting that the site is on the decline...but not unexpected. I don't list my experience in my SE profiles because a high ranked SE user mocked one of my questions, for example.

Comment: I fail to comprehend how irritating old users is a good thing!?

Comment: @simpleuser interesting point and one I'm mindful of. Low rep != skill. I know plenty of highly skilled programmers who have never posted on here or have low rep accounts. They're too busy working and rarely have the need to browse the site. As for the mockery, that's an unfortunate aspect of the species that really is not becoming.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque it's a hand. How irritating is that? Using a site that doesn't have client side validation and is painfully slow and takes 4 submissions of a form that keeps clearing, as it's reject on the server side and the UX is pitiful and doesn't save the inputs. That's an irritating UX. If the site fails (dies) there will be no more irritating hands for people to complain about. The hand is the least of our worries.

Comment: No @YvetteColomb, it is not "just" a hand! For some reasons, you are failing to listen to what many people have been trying to say, so, as you subtly suggested, I'll shut up.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque no, you're failing to read my [posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373158/what-does-our-long-term-community-need-what-does-our-long-term-community-need-t/373166#373166) or understand what I'm saying. So don't get all irrational under my post. I'm actually a human being and am tired of dealing with irrational outbursts under my posts. If you cannot see the site has much bigger problems that a UI hand, then clearly I've not been communicating clearly. It's not about `irritating old users`. Take it personally if you choose to, but don't carry on with me. I've over it.

Comment: Why does this website have a need to retain new users? I remember the first time I met developers online. Snark and derision was turned up to 11 everywhere from usenet to IRC if you didn't have the propensity to guess at what others will tell you when you ask a question (e.g. do more research, read a f*king book, what did you try, create a minimal test case, etc.). When you lack empathy, so does the internet. Not writing a test case or not reading the source is like writing in all caps. People are sensitive. And people don't want insensitive people around. So it makes sense to boot them off.

Comment: @nurettin without a sustained userbase the website will die. [this explains it well](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373191/3956566)

Comment: A very well written answer @YvetteColomb, thanks for the clarification. This and Tim Post's answer explains it better than the original blog post imho.

Comment: @Tschallacka honestly that blog was posted in too much of a hurry (IMO). There's a lot of damage as a result. The community is fatigued. It could have been handled a lot better. hindsight is so wise

Comment: @YvetteColomb I've had my hand in the rise and fall of communities i've created so far. The lessons I learned about it was if you focus to much on pleasing the core members and are not inviting/accepting or putting too much rules on the newbies at once, they will move to easier pastures. Just like you won't let a 1st year high school student not write an university paper, new users need a lot of leeway and are best triggered via rewards(badges, upvotes, etc..) to improve their behaviour. "rotten apples" should be banned/removed asap since they will poison the batch. balancing growth vs culling

Comment: @Tschallacka please write an answer to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373158/what-does-our-long-term-community-need-what-does-our-long-term-community-need-t) I'd like to hear more of your thoughts.

Comment: Did Tim Post really say that "SO is on the decline"?  All I could find in the article you linked was that "New users just don't stick around anywhere close to how they did a few years ago."  That's nowhere near as sweeping a generalization.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 There is a nebulous hand-waving assertion being bandied around that failing to retain new users will cause the death of Stack Overflow, presumably because new users are more likely to click adverts which make the site money. But as usual, there has been zero evidence provided to back up this assertion, and of course that completely ignores other sources of revenue from e.g. SO Careers, as well as the fact that low-quality new users don't stick around ANYWAY. Unsurprisingly then, pretty much anyone capable of logical thought is taking all this ballyhoo with copious amounts of NaCl.

Comment: @IanKemp you might be right. I did ask Shog for feedback and he was happy with it. Doesn't mean there's a shred of truth in it. At the end of the day I'm trying to put the pieces together without all the information. Oh an many months of changing the site to ensure new users are more welcome is more than a nebulous hand-waving. The network stated clearly that the site was alienating many people. None of us know how much revenue is generated from careers, etc

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 I'm not sure. That was the implication of that post. Tim's since written another [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373227/3956566). Whatever the motivation, the network want more users sticking around, that's been made clear.

Comment: I am not convinced that the decrease of the user base is due to "scaring off" of new users. That would mean the snark has increased in the latter years, has it. Not sure that is true. My theory is that, instead, all the questions that newbies could ask have been asked already. And that new people visit here, find their answer, and then leave again without feeling the need to post.

Comment: @MrLister this is what the network is telling us. Tim's latest answer delves into it more deeply. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373169/why-is-it-important-for-corporate-so-to-maintain-a-fast-new-user-growth-rate/373227#373227

Comment: "I suggest we work together as a community, as in the coming years, there won't be a community if we don't." I like the answer, even though the outlook at the end might be a bit too pessimistic.

Comment: @MrLister "And that new people visit here, find their answer, and then leave again without feeling the need to post." That's not how it works. Just look at how few of the new questions are closed as duplicates. They ask their question nevertheless and it does get answered. SO is currently in help-desk mode, not in encyclopedia building mode.

Comment: Oh and maybe it has also something to do with the fact that there are sometimes a lot of answers and you might forget a user is new when you come to the last answer

Comment: @YvetteColomb example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52082997/edit-c-sharp-windowsform-in-another-location-in-editor so a bunch of guys take no time to downvote and put this question on hold (2 of them also pass rude comment which i flagged)! This guy is new and has not been guided. Because this is on HOLD, I am unable to answer this, but I know exactly what he asked. I also edited the question, but still cant answer. I propose I should be able to answer even when its on hold, or I should be able to remove hold if I am 100% certain. I am going to sleep so more hrs wasted for OP now.

Comment: and i just saw that question has been completely removed! This is the typical old SO that you dont want! Lets see if something can be done about that question still. There was nothing wrong with it except that it was not worded right, but I got it, i rephrased it, I have an answer for it, it was a perfectly valid question. This is really frustrating. Some guys wont take the joy and pain of answering the question, but will feel it an achievement of spending hours marking questions as confusing.

Comment: @user734028 the question is unclear. If I undelete it, are you able to edit it to make it clear and provide an answer? P.s. next time raise a flag on the post rather than pinging me on the site. :)

Comment: i already edited it, do you have access to the one I edited? but it was deleted later on.

Comment: @user734028 it honestly doesn't make sense. I'm sure you understand it, but most people will be struggling. Anyway I must go I'm really busy. Sorry.

Answer (score -2):

As a fairly new user of the site I would like to share my experience with the "new contributor" tag next to my answers (and questions - i haven't asked one yet).

### Why the "new contributor" tag is a good thing

As you have mentioned in your post, seeing the tag will remind people that this person is new to the site. I totally agree with showing the tag there, responses and comments will take this into account. As a new contributor the "fear of a duplicate post/etc" is persistent, the tag is one step towards overcoming that fear. People might take a few more seconds when replying to a post and clarify the whole situation.

In my opinion the effect of overcoming this fear and therefore using the site to its full potential applies to replies as well. As a "newbie" you might be convinced that your technical know-how does not stand the high requirements of the website. Thus, your answer might not be perfect. **But** by showing-off that "Hello I am new, please keep that in mind" I might be more confident in posting my answer even if there might be a mistake.

The tag also has a link to the code of conduct which delivers the message: "Please read this to write a good answer and learn how we want to communicate here". This is also reasonable to show to a new user because not everyone goes through the tutorials after sign-up just to ask one urgent question. It does not even have to be clicked - just by "being there" it conveys a message.

---

Long story short: 
My personal perception of all the "warnings" has been throughout positive. I think this has the right effect on new contributors to convince them to adapt their style of writing to the guidelines and to transform them into the community members you want to have here in the long term.

---

### Update after mason's comments

My intention was to show the point of view of a new user and the effects it might have **on a new user**. The tag being displayed to me as a new user (underneath my username) was the one I have been speaking about - the other one in/or above the answer box was not the target of my post because I could not represent the point of view of an experienced user and I haven't seen it before.
[See both here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314287/come-take-a-look-at-our-new-contributor-indicator?cb=1)

I would like to clarify again, I would not expect special treatment for being tagged as the new one. In my opinion this provides information (which may be redundant due to the reputation that is already displayed) of a user being the new one.

Personally, I would definately choose to use the tag as a new user if it was an optional choice, because I appreciate comments to enhance future answers. So if an experienced user points out an issue with my question/answer by voting,  I would like to know what the reason was, to change it in this specific post/future posts.

**As this might apply to most users (not just the new ones)**, it could still influence the more experienced user to write a comment on his/her vote even if he/she thinks that the reason for his/her vote is quite obvious and the author could figure this out him-/herself. A post being duplicate or not specifying any sign of research/commitment is obviously not what this kind of feedback is needed for.

While writing this I figured out that a solution to the "a new user does not mean he/she is inexperienced" issue could be making the tag optional for new users. This would also solve the issue of creating new accounts [(issue has been pointed out here)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314287/come-take-a-look-at-our-new-contributor-indicator?cb=1). But this should not be discussed here.

Comment: I don't agree with this answer but at least 1) it _attempts_ to answer with a good level of quality, and 2) an answer from a new contributor on meta must be encouraged.

Comment: I don't care if you're new or not, I'm still going to treat you the same. My standards don't drop. If you are unable to find an obvious duplicate, I will downvote your question for lack of research. There's no reason to fear: just do a decent amount of research before asking your question. So no, this banner does nothing. By the way, if your question is "urgent", that's not our problem. The standards don't drop just because you perceive your issue as being more important than everyone else's.

Comment: @mason I think you might have taken my answer too personal. I share the same opinion about an obvious duplicate. I have not tried to stop anyone from downvoting a question when it is obvious that the answer to the subject has been posted several times on the website. I did not say that "my question" was urgent, I even stated that I haven't asked one, yet. I just noticed that you obtain a badge for going through the tutorial and I discoverd many new users on SO without it - so I thought that might be the reason for it. My intention of this post was to give an insight of an actual newcomer.

Comment: @mason Well, yesterday I wrote my first answer on SO. I am not as experienced as you might be at this point so I may struggle to express myself explaining a technical topic because I have not done this at a regular basis so far. The banner will display my "newbieness" and therefore someone might actually propose an edit before just downvoting an answer. With this in mind you might actually write something instead of sitting in front of the screen and thinking: Well, I could have said this. I had this several times: Writing an answer to a question and then second-guessing it and not posting it.

Comment: If someone wanted to downvote a question, do you really think that telling them to be welcoming is going to change that? And why do you think it's a good idea to treat anyone different based on their experience? The expectations don't change for you. For the most part, if your answer is 1) technically correct 2) written in understandable English 3) doesn't encourage security violations or violate other clear best practices. then you don't have much to worry. We are supposed to vote based on the quality of the post, not the newness of the account. And from what I can tell, that's what happens

Comment: @CrimsonMike That's just wishful thinking. The banner is an attempt to change the community to vote based not on quality, but on who's asking/answering. That goes against everything this community is built on. Rather than achieving the more welcoming atmosphere you say you want, it's far more likely to drive a divisive wedge between new and experienced users.

Comment: Answering your first question: I honestly don't know that but I think the chance is higher than without the tag being displayed. I don't expect any special treatment for someone with a different experience level but the point is that a recommendation or any type of suggestion is far more helpful for future answers of the new user. I would not label this as "special treatment" because the whole community does benefit from it. It is not said that this can not be done on answers/questions of users that are not new. In the end we all would like to meet those expectations but may struggle to do so.

Comment: @mason "The banner is an attempt to change the community to vote based not on quality, but on who's asking/answering" - Instead of voting: suggesting an edit or actually editing it is probably the way to go. As stated above by Yvette, the goal that should be achieved is growing the user base. A welcoming atmosphere is required to keep new users on the site. I totally agree that voting is still the most important part but explaining a vote would be even more helpful to someone like me. I appreciate your comment for example - so I might be able to enhance the whole meaning of my post.

Comment: You want us to perform different actions based on the experience level of the user. That, by definition, is special treatment. Whether the community benefits from special treatment you can debate if you want to, but our community has been built around a foundation that it doesn't matter who you are: as long as you provide quality content, we'll appreciate your contribution. That's what benefits the community, not accepting low quality content just because it came from someone who is new.

Comment: Stack Exchange the company might be interested in growing the userbase. But I think most of us here do not care about that. Stack Overflow's goal shouldn't be to attract as many people as possible. It's to be a site for high quality questions and answers directly related to programming issues.

Comment: The solution is to explain the vote as you did here. You are free to do what you want to do, nobody would be forced to vote/not vote. Quote: "as long as you provide quality content, we'll appreciate your contribution" - yes, this is the point - so we have to achieve two things: Encourage the user to use the site and still make clear that his/her contribution does not meet the requirements. I think the tag might be a solution for achieving both. Anyway, I would like to move this discussion to a chat but I don't think I can open one, yet. We both made our point clear.

Comment: @CrimsonMike Editing a post is not a substitute for providing accurate feedback on the post's quality.  Sure, people are welcome to edit posts, but making an edit doesn't remove the need to vote on a post's quality.  Also note that there are *lots* of people that edit *lots* of posts.  Not just new users' posts.  This has never really been a problem.  It's a feature most other site's don't even have.  That SO has it at all is a big step up from any alternative.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not familiar with editing a post and the notification process (what details will you see of an edit, etc). Therefore, I am not able to know details concerning this at that point. As I explained in my update of the post, I think voting and giving the reason why is everything that a new user needs as feedback to develope. I do really not want to drift too far of my original statement which was just meant to be an opinion/experience I had so far. For any additional discussion, that goes beyond that experience, I am not able to give my opinion on because I have not tried it yet

Answer (score -7):

This makes sense and is appropriate. People abuse the answers on a regular basis, and there’s a lot of content in answers that violates the [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct). Much of it is deleted before it’s seen by many people, and most of it does not merit a Rude or Abusive flag, especially because answers (unlike comments) are community-editable. But that doesn’t mean abusive behavior in the answers section is at all rare.

Put differently, this statement of yours is *extremely* optimistic about how people actually use the site:

> Answers contain technical information.

Good answers do that. Things people post as “answers” when they’re annoyed at an OP, not so much.

I’ll admit that I’m not the biggest fan of the “new contributor” warning. **I don’t think we should have it anywhere.** A user’s newness and reputation are irrelevant to the quality of a question or answer, and *we* should be respectful to all users, new or not. But I do see some value to it. And **if** we’re going to have the warning, it makes sense to remind people of it before they go off on a long-form version of “RTFM, use a debugger, and then just hire a real programmer.”

As an aside, if a user is truly a jerk in an answer to a new user’s question even after seeing that warning, well, let’s just say moderator actions may be less lenient if we have to step in.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if people already ignore the fact that the button says "Post Your Answer" and proceed to post comments and questions that way, there's no amount of text or images that will keep them from doing it. And it's frequent, just follow the Natty bot in the SO biotics chat for an hour and you'll see at least 2 posts pop up of things that aren't answers. Now, if we're concerned about people being rude or otherwise violate the CoC with the answer box,  which we also do see several times a day, the "New Contributor" banner won't have any more effect than the existing text does.

Comment: My comments are coming from the ♦ moderator perspective. While SO botics does great work, I can assure you the abuse and NAA problems are worse than you likely realize. Abusive and NAA content is posted many times per hour, not just several times per day. How much impact the banner has remains to be seen, but it’s at least an effort to encourage civil behavior.

Comment: errr, then this text should be 'This section is for answers, don't post "yup, same problem" or "I agree with xxx"' for newcomers (the "protected" question text has the same description). My point is: no need to remind the extra niceness in _answers_. It's missing the point

Comment: @Jean-François I think I may not have made my point clearly. My point isn’t that too many people post things that aren’t answers. That’s true, but Davy brought that up, not me. My point is that even real answers are often very rude or abrasive. They are not always, as you said, just technical information. They are often very pointed & unkind. As a mod, I see more of this than I did before I became a mod. My argument is: ***if*** we’re going to have a “new contributor” warning (which is debatable), having it show for both commenters & answerers makes some sense.

Comment: but why only for new users then? I'm "old" but if I lazily ask bad php questions (which I don't know at all), people will probably treat me as a newbie and will bash me in answers (ok I can downvote/edit/delete)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre If I we’re a cynical person I’d say it’s because old users don’t impress investors. A constant stream of new users impresses investors, and that needs to be achieved at any cost to the old users and quality of the site. Luckily im not a cynic...

Comment: aaahh I get it. I'll stick the stack overflow logo on my bike.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That’s a key point, though: experienced users are *expected* to know better. New users are not always familiar with SO, which is very different from other sites, even other Q&A sites. Our definitions of “off-topic” and “shows effort” in particular, can be surprising and overwhelming. We shouldn’t put up with garbage, no-effort questions from anyone, but we should probably remember that we were all new here, once. That means that adding a reminder not to lash out at new users is at least a positive effort, not the end of SO as we know it.

Comment: okay, I get your point. But bashing isn't tolerated, new user or not. It can be edited out if the rest of the answer is good, BTW.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre You’re absolutely right about that, of course. The goal of the warnings, as I understand it, is to stop bad behavior preemptively. It’s a better experience for everyone and less taxing on the reviewers and moderators if the content starts out polite, instead of having to be edited into shape.

Comment: I'm sorry this got so many downvotes. We need a "be nice to the mods" banner :) the mods aren't writing the rules.

Comment: Just use NAA flags instead.

Comment: @user202729 I’m not sure what you mean (instead of what?), but more flagging isn’t the solution. We already handle about 2,000 flags per day, and that doesn’t scale well. Besides, flags are only useful for after a bad post is written. The goal is to prevent the bad post. Flags don’t help at all with that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that that comment is saritical. We all know that votes are on posts, not users.

Comment: @user202729 Of course.

Comment: In an ideal world, all posts follow the rules and there are no flags.  However SE can'tcome up with a way to achieve it, the question/answer-block/flags doesn't suffice. Warning may be a good way, but "new contributor" warning has nothing to do with that.

Comment: "My point isn’t that too many people post things that aren’t answers. That’s true, but Davy brought that up, not me" My point wasn't that some number about how many people do it, my point was that people ignore the existing text that tells them to post an answer and post NAA and rude content, so we can't expect more text to make any difference. The stuff about the Natty bot was just so that anyone could see the kind of things that are posted with blatant disregard for the text on the button they're clicking.

Comment: @Davy Fair enough; thanks for clarifying.

Comment: why is this answer being down voted so much!!!!!!

Comment: @user734028 probably mod bashing. meta downvotes are cheap, mods represent authority, and when they say things that tend to support an unpopular feature, they get downvoted.

Comment: @user734028 (serious answer) Because people disagree with it.

Comment: The downvotes on this answer are a great example of some of the problems with this community.

Comment: @jnylen So expressing our disagreement is an example of a "problem with the community"? I hardly think so.

Answer (score -25):

I think this is designed to remind people to be welcoming, and thus encourage newer users to stick around.

There is a huge difference between these two ways of responding to a question:

- This question is not allowed here, read the rules
- Hi xxx, this seems like a "fix my code" type question without sufficient detail, so it's probably not a good fit for this site. Please read our [guidelines on asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

The first will drive away new users. The second will help them stay around and become productive members and eventually moderators of the site, as well as helping to turn around the often-negative reputation of SO on the web.

Comment: Hi jnylen, seems like you're missing the point by a mile: the 2 ways you've decribed are _comment_ responses, not _answers_. My question was about this message _in the answer box_

Comment: Same principle applies. Maybe the design could be improved or 
the intent clarified, but reminding people to be nice is not a bad thing.

Comment: okay, but in that case, it should be reminded whatever the OP is, new or old.

Comment: I can think of at least 3 reasons not to do that.

Comment: It's more important for new users because they are more likely to ask questions that need improvement.

Comment: It's more important for new users because they are more likely to leave and never come back if they have a bad experience.

Comment: Showing the message all the time for everyone makes woole answering questions more likely to ignore it.

Comment: Both of these would be unacceptable in an *answer*. It would be good if you could come up with examples that read like answers not comments to prove your point, since OP's argument as I read it is basically "there's no place for emotions *in answers* anyways".

Comment: @jnylen If you argue that "same principle applies" you need to explain it in more details. I can see no way the "same principle" can be applied to an answer -- as said in the question, answers contains technical information.