# Why is it important for corporate SO to maintain a fast new user growth rate?

Tags: discussion, new-users, stack-exchange

Following the plethora of posts on the "be extra nice" initiative, I started wondering. **If the goal is**

> Create a repository of high quality Q&A to cover programming issues

It seems like the only thing that would be important is that **knowledge contained with the users** grows at the same rate as **new programming technologies**.

The sheer amount of users seems irrelevant - even today, in almost all programming issues (barring some of the more esoteric ones, I agree), some sort of response should appear in minutes, if not seconds, which seems fast enough. At some point a question asker cannot react to the responses fast enough.

When a new technology arrives, it is important to get some new users proficient in it, but I don't think that's nearly as much as the "be extra nice" initiative is going for. In addition, some of the experienced programmers on the site (of which I am not) are likely to be some of the first experts anyway, even lessening the need for new users.

The amount of new programmers per year grows much more than the new languages/technologies/common questions, **what is so important about decreasing user attrition**?

At some point I would expect SO to be saturated, with new **good** questions being quickly addressed by an existing/slowly growing database. Maybe that point is now?

**What about the $$$?**

as [@Dukeling gently alludes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373179/6881240), it is all about the money. So, what are the metrics SO needs to consider? (under construction)

1. New user growth attrition
2. Question growth attrition
3. **Veteran** user attrition
4. Good question % of total
5. New language/technology/API/CS PhD/whatever you want to call it growth rate

If SO focuses heavily on (1) and (2) to account for (5) (and over-doing it), at the expense of 3 and 4, will it really be worth it in the long run?

Or maybe, the most controversial questions, what is the average worth of a new user, after, say a year; Or, how should corporate rank new users by $$$ as a function of time? I wonder if this has actually been done, it does not seem far-fetched.

**I want to address the [conference analogy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373191/6881240) made by NicolBolas**

The drive home point of the analogy is that a growing user base is crucial to maintain a fast response in the technological evolving world. Especially, in the more esoteric, less followed tags, acquiring a user base is important.

I would like to point out that really is just the gut of my question - In the long run, is amassing the general population of posters to the user base conducive to the betterment of SO (a-la saving the site)? Even for the least visited tags, will it really make them better? The reason I asked is because it did not seem so to me, and offered other metrics that seem relevant, but I may be wrong.

Comment: You mean apart from $$$?

Comment: @Dukeling Isn't the business centered around job advertising? Seems like keeping a select group of "snobby elites" would be be better than a huge amount of generic "I learned C today!" users (I know I am generalizing, but that's what you do in business, no?). Otherwise a business owner can just use some other  resource locating quality for hire. I think I might even add that to the question.

Comment: I'm not sure we can make the assumption they want a fast growth rate. We can make the assumption they don't want a permanent negative growth. It's important to run with the facts as closely as possible.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Referring to [tim's post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314302/are-we-creating-divisions-in-our-quest-to-make-new-users-welcome/314519#314519), *"I'm not going to post the exact rates, and I'm not going to post the exact metrics that we use to consider someone 'lost' as far as likely to re-engage"*, so there are no facts to run with. My points stands though. I'll even go as far as to ask, even if 0 users join from now until August next year, do you feel the quality/usefulness of SO will plummet?

Comment: @Dukeling Agreed with the snobby part, though I was going for highly proficient coders (guess I am just jealous). The second part I do not understand - Will "being the go-to resource" be affected by a very slowly growing community in the current state of things? Are the new APIs/languages sprouting up so fast? 10s a days? thousands? I think that is the real metric.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll add it the question after I have collected some more comments.

Comment: @Dukeling where are the snobby elites today?  All I see are deadbeats with homework-dumps:(

Comment: @MartinJames They're the ones getting reprimanded for asking "what have you tried?" and saying "you can get the answer by typing this question as is into Google".

Comment: @Dukeling IIRC, 'what have you tried?' is no longer accepted as a comment.  In fact, it's actively rejected:)

Comment: @YvetteColomb A fast growth rate is really the only rational explanation for the nonsense that's been pushed lately.

Comment: @Andy [not at all](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373191/3956566). If the site is showing signs of poor health that could lead to the site's death, I wouldn't necessarily refer to it as nonsense. More like CPR.

Comment: @kabanus [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373191/3956566). There seems to be ignorance on how businesses run (from you and others) and there's information the site has that we don't.

Comment: @YvetteColomb That's fair to say I may have misunderstood something fundamental in business, but as I replied to NicolBolas, that is my exact question. Does SO think just amassing users will better the site, and if so why? Will it help the more esoteric tags? Help maintain the prolific ones? That is the entire the point of my question - do we want to add every programmer that is born to the site (exaggerating, I know)? My main point is that technologies are born much slower than programmers, so perhaps relying on some saturation is possible?

Comment: By the way, I do not think if SO tries to maximize profit that is a bad thing. I am wondering about what is the best way to do that.

Comment: Technologies are born and develop extremely quickly. The pace of software development is faster than most sciences. Think of medicine and cancer research it takes years to test and release drugs. Platforms release buggy IDEs and APIs as part of the SDLC. Release now, fix bugs later. An phone that is 5 years old is considered old.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Agree about the phone, and buggy environments, but can you really say new phones are new technology? The latter is often addressed by the same developers, and the former, I think (and I think I have some knowledge in the matter) can barely be called "new" technology. More re-branded, more of the same with some optimizations, etc. I guess I did not really define what "new" means, another fair point.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I do not mean to say you are wrong. I am wondering what are your thoughts - should we increase the new user-base as fast as possible or SO will struggle? If you think so, that is a fair answer.

Comment: @kabanus I didn't think you were being critical at all. I know we're discussing. Increasing the new-user base without discernment is what got us into this problem in the first place (my thoughts). We need to retain quality users who are going to help curate the site and stick around. Currently there's so much discontent, we also need to focus on improving morale for our existing community. I've gone into it in more depth in other posts. I honestly don't know what the answers are. I just have ideas. Not very helpful sorry :/

Comment: @YvetteColomb I think if more people were like you (and I have read your other posts - which sometimes seem like they are from different people, which I like a lot!), then a healthy discussion would yield better answers and results (including for SO revenue, I wager).

Comment: well that's nice to hear. I'm by no means perfect. I did help run a business for many years. I also think being older brings a different perspective. Just the sheer volume of life experience helps.

Comment: A natural goal of the company would be, that askers pay for the answers, and in the spirit of this (and many other questions) guess what the answerers will get then ...

Comment: This is just my unsubstantiated pet theory: maybe SE/SO are preparing for a buyout like GitHub. Why else suddenly focus so much on growth and "toxicity"?

Comment: We're not preparing for a buyout, not even a long shot. Source: I work here in senior management and have fully-vested options. If you see me tweeting about problems like not being able to decide on what Rolex to buy, worry.

Comment: I would expect most of SO's revenue (from questions on SO) actually comes from anonymous users, not *any* authenticated users, whether new or old.  (Given that they make up the vast majority of page views, and because most users have the privilege to see much fewer ads.)  So what's important is that SO has quality questions that people are searching for and are satisfied with the answers to.

Comment: It's almost like we didn't learn from history. The WWW mantra of old ("everyone's a publisher!") hasn't made the internet a more reliable source of information, any more than the welcome wagon is going to make Stack Overflow a more valuable resource. SO is an *exclusive* community, geared towards professional software developers. Being more inclusive is inevitably going to deviate from the paramount objective: Providing quality answers to quality questions. The day my mom decides to ask for help with her computer on SO while browsing Seasoned Advice is the day I'm leaving for good.

Comment: fyi, the number of "active experts" decreases steadily since 2014. We are currently at 2011 level: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/341448/number-of-active-experts-per-week#graph

Comment: Eh, thank you for that @TimPost :-) First time I've smiled in Meta since many a day...

Comment: What makes you think user growth rate is important, rather than clicks from Google? You can view the site without registering, and SO can make money from people browsing the site, even though they aren't actively participating.

Comment: @jfs Coincidentally (or possibly not), the rise levels off in 2013 at about the same time "what have you tried?" was banned from comments.

Comment: @Izkata "User must demonstrate a minimal knowledge of the topic" was removed somewhere around 2014, along with various other quantity over quality changes, favouring beginners/students over professional & enthusiast programmers.

Comment: @Lundin because several posts and actions by the staff indicated it is. The answer here I will probably accept eventually by Tim explains it some more. My original thought was that it was not, hence the question.

Comment: @AkselA the query is for the stackoverflow site alone.

Comment: @jfs: Ah, yes, I misread the captions.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

> This is long, even after I tried to shorten it. You can skip to the bottom bullets for some key take-aways, but if this really interests you, I suggest reading the whole thing. Sorry about the book.

The new user growth rate doesn't have to be fast, it has to be *commensurate*. And by that, I mean on any random 90-day sampling, you see more users staying and climbing over 250 rep than leaving in aggregate.

Those that leave fall into two major buckets:

- Got to at *least* 500 rep with every sign that they could continue to contribute positively. In there, you've got:

  - Made it to 3k+
  - Made it to 10k+
  - Became a trusted user
- Didn't get to at least 500 rep, in there you've got:

  - Didn't do *anything* but create an account, favorite and subscribe to a few tags, shared a few posts, etc. Positive but read-only existence, and then vanished.
  - Didn't unlock even basic creature comforts. Maybe 1 or 2 posts.
  - Got to between 50 and 250 rep and just vanished, no signs of contributions not being welcome (by votes / flags / etc).
  - Got between 1 - 50 rep, but obviously struggled (we can usually pinpoint how / why).

So, if you get past 250 rep, you at least (statistically) *stand a chance* of having another shot at leaving when you hit 500 rep, and then again at regular intervals as you climb the ladder. The bucket between 0 - 250 becomes pretty important because it feeds every other bucket.

#### People leave for many reasons. Trying to explain *everything* is foolish.

***But***, you should always try and figure out what you can learn.

Those that left *past* getting 500 rep are actually the easiest to explain. We've looked at it over a dozen (literally) ways and no matter how we scope the phenomenon, we can pretty clearly see that:

- It wasn't us. Maybe they lost interest, changed jobs, passed away (morbid, but common), lost the ability to post publicly about work, etc. In essence, stuff we *maybe* could capture better and account for? But, if we're honest with ourselves, we probably can't intervene much here, life happens.
- It *was* us, and we can clearly see why. A false positive on voting reversal scripts, folks losing rep because someone else removed their account, folks losing rep because something got deleted, or a thousand other little ways where if we look *hard* enough, one or several events stand out as a probable culprit or at least catalyst. DAG works on mining and running tests around this stuff to try and take advantage of what our own data is telling us.

This is an interesting journey  because you often don't realize that you were looking at things completely wrong until you've... well, you've been there, ever had to confront an early decision that proved fatal near the end of a project? That's why we now have a full time data team and UX researchers (I had no idea that was a thing until we hired them) and increasingly better models.

#### We have historically sucked at parsing outside feedback.

Even considering how much criticism is in the air right now, ***we open ourselves to more criticism than any mature company that I've ever encountered in the technology sector.*** In fact for every single site we have, there's an accompanying place where people are *encouraged* to speak what's on their mind. We call this **inside feedback** because:

1. It's a dynamic where *we* hold all of the power because it's our platform (which is why we try our best to be as liberal as possible and allow as much room as we can for passion as long as an *attempt* at respect is maintained).
2. It tends to come mostly from people that *know* how things work, which is why they can make great arguments for changing things, even if we don't agree with them. The small rep barrier for child meta sites alone pretty much says *if you want to talk about how we do stuff, you need some prior participation*. [Meta means murder](https://blog.codinghorror.com/listen-to-your-community-but-dont-let-them-tell-you-what-to-do/) and at *our* scale, the barrier to entry *does* need to be slightly higher than "I think I might have an opinion about [thing]".

That means, **outside feedback** generally comes from e-mail, Twitter, Facebook, Reddit, Hacker News, Blogs, Conferences, etc. The only commonality in these sources are *that they are extremely difficult to quantify and parse in aggregate*. Going back to the people that leave - we can use the same software that monitors our network connectivity to alert us of a sudden change in *users we have*.

We failed to capture the entirety of *users we just weren't getting* (which suddenly makes that 0-250 rep bucket a lot bigger), and why, and how much of that was related to the perceived hostility of the site. We knew it was a problem (I've personally lost sleep over it for the last 4 years as I saw trends but had only anecdotal evidence). Until we finally hired and on-boarded people that *dream in data*, we didn't know how *bad* it was.

#### The good news is, it's not that bad yet.

At around 30 - 35% attrition rate on average (that's all I'm going to share, and it's only for discussion), we're not doing too bad. In fact, *right now*, we're doing pretty darn good. And we ***absolutely, positively, most decidedly*** do not want that number to reach anywhere near 50%, because that's the point where stuff gets real and Joel takes away our standing desks.

It's difficult to speculate on prospects for a community of this size because frankly, we're writing the history academics are using to make models. But I (and lots of other folks much smarter than I am) believe that we have crossed an event horizon of sorts, and while new users should never be commoditized as "a dime a dozen", I don't *think* we'll ever reach a point where we've burned through the market faster than it grows.

#### But this isn't about $$$. It's about everything.

I guess money is a part of everything, and we're not going to pretend that we're not a business, but stopping there is short-sighted.

Until a few years ago, Stack Overflow was kind of elusive when it came to community metrics. The thinking we established based on what we learned from hundreds of other sites just broke *horribly* when we applied it to SO. What we knew from the network made what we were seeing on SO make even *less* sense in many cases; we just didn't have the tools and people we needed to really study it, and *we didn't know we lacked those.* We just attributed it to 'scale'.

Yes, more users sometimes eventually translates into more revenue for us. In some cases we can charge a little more for ads, in other cases it might inspire more creative partnerships with companies using new technologies as new sub-communities form around those tags. But broadly, more users *will not* translate into more revenue unless we can find ways to provide enough value to those users that they positively engage.

But had we been able to understand and better parse the different kinds of signals we were getting two years ago or even sooner, you'd have seen us prioritize this then. This is the kind of thing you want to nip in the early stages, so to say, and it's not *just* Stack Overflow that we're trying to help.

#### So putting that all together:

- Our success depends on finding innovative ways of delighting people that tend to come from a very technical audience. Sheer numbers just occupy a database unless we can inspire those folks to do something.
- We absolutely must course-correct on outright ignoring and failing to act on outside feedback. That doesn't make innovating and delighting folks that stick around less important, it's just a different part of the machine that happens to need urgent attention (largely, because we ignored it, because we didn't see the forest for the trees). *All* feedback needs sunlight to disinfect and we have to find a way to embrace perspectives of non-participants. We're getting  better.
- We're still a growing and relatively small company with limited resources. While we don't struggle and thrash around in the name of profitability, we're still going to struggle and thrash around as we encounter even scarier problems that come with becoming more established. We're *way* more public and open than anyone else and as you can see, it has been a heck of a ride. We wish we could do everything, right now, and make everyone happy. We'll get there.
- We can't say money isn't part of it, we're a business, that's like saying oxygen isn't a part of being alive. And I think it's perfectly normal to connect knee-jerk-ish behavior to the *worst* possible cause, but we really wish you wouldn't do that, we can't always react to stuff *and* get sufficiently ahead of it in discussions here in the amount of time we feel that we need to act. We act on strategy, your input is a *big* part of that strategy, but there are other components.

#### Speaking of strategy ...

I've pushed my comfort level in the volume of what I've shared, and I'm not going to dive further into strategy with discussions about methodology, how I get my numbers, what we look at, how we plot certain things, etc. This is meta, you're welcome to accept our narrative *or* create your own, as long as you do it respectfully.

But there's really not much room for anything to hide, there's no boogeymen. It's not greed, it's us being stewards of what we've built.

We will (hopefully, very very soon) return focus to more *tangible* things that say "We <3 our core users!" instead of offering promises that we're working on it. This will probably resume after we finish annoying the heck out of a bunch more sites getting the unified theme so we can finally have one codebase where new features can just flow without 10 years of code smell.

And, frankly, paying down debt *is* the focus - everything else (including the sudden need to devote resources to new user experiences and preconceptions) are things that we *wish* could put off until we finish what we're doing. But when you realize OH CRAP EVERYTHING IS ON FIRE, ignoring or (worse) acquiescing to those circumstances is what leads to failure.

I'm happy to take questions but please understand that I've *already* over-shared to an extent. After almost 10 years of most of my time sinking into this beast we've built *every single day*, you can bet I'd be outta here if it was just about the money.

Comment: The question is: can you differentiate users losing interest, or making this a much lower priority, due to them simply being over the whole idea of helping build a Q&A, versus because they consider too much of the content to be low quality and that it's honestly just too draining to push past to find something actually worth reading, never mind answering.

Comment: I do not think I could have asked for a better answer. I appreciate your candor and forthrightness. I guess I was under the assumption most programmers (say 99.99%) were familiar with SO only when searching for a question (and not through reddit etc.), so they were not lost in the sense they wanted to join but were put off. It's cool you guys can check that. Do you mind commenting on whether you do compare growth rates to market growth rates? Please do not divulge any secrets, I'm must wondering if it's on the data dream team's mind.

Comment: And do you define "leaving" as abandoning their account completely, or do you look at people whose contributions simply dropped down to a near-negligible point?

Comment: @Dukeling There's a bit of unknown there, and when you don't know what you're _not_ competent at doing, it's difficult to assert that you're competent. However, the vast majority of _outside_ feedback points at problems separate from interestingness / captivating content for entry barriers, although we're certain it's a problem, it's difficult to say _how much_ of one. We can pretty comfortably assert that it's not nearly as much of a problem as what was slipping by in comments and such. But, again -  disclaimer: we don't know what we don't know, if that makes sense?

Comment: @Dukeling For your second question, 90 days of pretty much no activity _based on what you normally did_ is a good indicator of 'leaving', but if someone becomes active again, they just get counted on the positive side of a different sampling. On the other hand, 45 days seems to make sense in a lot of models that apply more uniformly to _all_ sites, so .. at least 45 days, 90 days is a good indicator, but certain patterns of use require specialized scoping, especially for read-only types. I'm sorry if that's even more confusing.

Comment: @Dukeling It also depends on what other experiments or building we've been up to during that period. Massive changes to logging in and signup really skew things, and introducing spam protection really skewed anon participation metrics, we've historically done a _very_ bad job of noting potential influencers in a way that's easily correlated (yay, historically, we're bad at history!). We're thankfully getting _a lot_ better at that in recent months.

Comment: @kabanus I can say that market growth rates are very hard to track, and this is compounded by _our_ annual survey being such a big influence in _how_ the market is tracked, but "yes-ish" is the best answer I can give. We know we need to get better at tracking  it, but  are a little further along than some others, if that helps.

Comment: Some indication of what *"We <3 our core users!"* will translate to in terms of long-requested features or tools would be welcome.

Comment: @PaulWhite If we go by the size of debt in terms of touches to effectiveness of helping the sites thrive, mod tools are probably at the top of the list of things we need to overhaul. That's kinda serendipitous, as in order to give mods better tools to handle comments in general, we kinda need to fix all of that. I hope to have some more news on that in the coming weeks.

Comment: That's a fair reply. I think this post, maybe with the q&a in the comments, should have come way earlier in this new process. Perhaps instead of another blog post... But no use crying over spilled milk, at least for me this post was helpful and even comforting.

Comment: I appreciate this explanation, and your recent one on MSE (that Yvette linked from yesterday's question here. I need to study that one a bit more.). You folks, and you especially, are insanely awesome at being open. Thank you for taking the time to write this.

Comment: @TimPost Haven't read the full post yet, but my gut reaction is a little surprise that SO measure user retention based on rep-gain (250 and 500 metrics), rather than repeat visits from the same IP or registrations. Or do you separate users and visitors into two different buckets? Or should I just read the whole answer? :-P

Comment: "At around 30 - 35% attrition rate on average..." I'm unclear what this means. Are you saying the user base is shrinking by 30% to 35% over... some unspecified time period? Or is this a decrease in the growth rate? Or what?

Comment: @TylerH We go more by just rep, and we do make light use of cookies, but we don't use 'sessions' in any sense one might see as conventional (perf and privacy reasons). This limits what we track _even when_ folks are logged-in. We track a visit, but beyond that, you kind a need to do _something_ in order to show as engaged (registration is one of those somethings). So we won't count you as missing if all you did was vote for 90 days, but if that keeps up, you might be 3/4ths missing at 180 days out, based on prior activity, depending on the model used [1/3]

Comment: There are also more absolute models, e.g. "Did they do anything this period? They were present! else, no!" but those paint a very jagged picture. [2/3]

Comment: While we measure this stuff in a variety of ways and we're still making lots of mistakes, we do _not_ go by IP addresses because they simply aren't reliable. We've got offices where _thousands_ of people use the same IP (Hello Samsung! Hello Microsoft! IBM! etc) so it's just noise for the most part. I don't think we'll implement any more advanced tracking metrics post-GDPR even though we could justify a business case for it just out of the potential pain in the butt factor. [3/3]

Comment: @jpmc26 Aggregate (and I hope you understand that I can't be much more specific). It's a combination of "veteran" users that go dark, along with the sum of non-veteran users that essentially just bounce off of us like hitting a wall. I will say there are two reasons why I don't elaborate more.  (1) I'm sure the number isn't entirely off-base, but we're still refining how we derive it, which makes explaining it suboptimal at the moment and [1/2]

Comment: (2) it's a little too close to strategy at this point thus guarded _mostly_ because we don't fully understand it yet, so we don't know if it's a hairy spider or that ugly holiday sweater we bought last year hanging in the closet. We may come up with a way to make this metric more public (maybe even just for moderators), I think it would be useful, I just don't know if it's _possible_.  [2/2]

Comment: @TimPost I don't understand why you would *combine* users not assimilating with active users leaving. As far as I can tell, doing so mixes separate concerns and doesn't represent any sort of meaningful quantity. The more immediately meaningful quantities are the total user base growth/shrink rate and new user retention, and perhaps some analysis of how they interact. Statistics can be extremely useful, but it is incredibly easy to paint a false picture by focusing on the wrong numbers. You get a more accurate picture by considering a range of them, rather than focusing on one kind.

Comment: @jpmc26: It does represent something meaningful: the flow of users away from the site. Those who were on it who decided not to be anymore, even if they were on it for mere minutes. But don't assume that the number by itself is all they know; that's merely the number Tim is presenting. The aggregate number is one they want to shrink, but from Tim's post (heh), it's clear that they're not ignoring the distinctions of why some users stop using the site.

Comment: @jpmc26 We do. I'm _presenting_ as aggregate for the purposes of discussion, we're developing _very_ different models for understanding the difference between burnout / fatigue and just people's natural tendency to wander off once they've done all they came to do, for instance. This also cross correlates with effects new users that 'bounce' quickly might have on veteran departures (correlation _or_ causation) and a lot of other mining. As I note, I'm reticent to discuss it deeply, but we _are_ looking at a lot of different things.

Comment: @jpmc26 Also: If that weren't complicated enough, it changes for ... who knows why ... every few months (even outside of usual seasonal stuff). That's even _more_ head-scratching and digging we're doing, and partly why we're just not yet ready to present it as a whole, we only have an outline of a narrative. It's substantially complete now, but still lots of questions. You could get lost  for years studying this stuff.

Comment: Tim do you mind commenting on [@jfs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373169/why-is-it-important-for-corporate-so-to-maintain-a-fast-new-user-growth-rate/373299#comment625437_373169)'s comment? in particular [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/341448/number-of-active-experts-per-week#graph)? That seems more trouble than completely new users bouncing off.

Comment: It is rather interesting that you categorize these buckets by rep, when in reality rep is quite a poor classification since how much you get depends vastly on the tag you're in and the time you've joined, so the real measure of participation is constantly shifting.

Comment: It's interesting this post doesn't mention the *quality* of users, by this I mean do they *all* count under "professional or enthusiast"; would a survey be able to discern anything? This point is the [most upvoted comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373158/what-does-our-long-term-community-need-what-does-our-long-term-community-need-t#comment624481_373158) on a related post.

Comment: @jpp We've experimented with surveys previously and they yield .. _something_, how useful it is remains to be seen. We've run A/B tests where requests to take short surveys appear in modal dialogs after certain events fire, and get feedback about that particular experience (e.g asking questions). The problem with asking if professional or enthusiast is people tend to significantly exaggerate or underrate their experience. And the wording matters, too - e.g "are you solving a problem for work" doesn't make you a programmer, it could just mean you got stuck with an access database.

Comment: @TimPost, It's tough, but we have to face the facts. Both a content perspective (most theoretical / ideological canonicals have been asked & answered, so we are left *mostly* with application) and user perspective (more schools / workplaces incorporate programming as a *necessity* where previously irrelevant) point towards an adjustment. Technologies and uses do change, so good Q&A will never disappear *completely*. But we also have to adjust to demands faced in the real world and strike a balance, e.g. the new question template is definitely a good step.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback. I see the discussion has died out, so I'm accepting, I hope this answer and comments will be a good go to for everyone.

Comment: @TimPost I've thought about this for a long time, and I think I understand why the stat and the response bother me so much. They hide too much. If you look at only the aggregate, then you can't say anything about the underlying causes. One thing that's especially concerning is that SO has always considered an Eternal September effect, where knowledgeable users withdraw from the community, to be a serious risk that needed to be mitigated. This push is exactly the opposite, but the data you're presenting doesn't tell us anything about whether SO is having trouble just retaining users who...

Comment: ...post high quality content due to the flood of poor quality questions. Furthermore, if this was all really just about, "We have this data and think it means this and are going to act on it," you owe everyone an apology for not just presenting it that way from day one. Instead, SO has cast inexperienced users as mere victims and done nothing to even *acknowledge* the quality problems that we all know contribute to frustration with low quality posts and the users behind them. That approach has dealt a serious blow to the community's trust SO worked so hard to earn.

Comment: @jpmc26 We've put ourselves in the position to being open to questioning about essentially _anything_ at _any time_. If we're reticent to answer, we're hiding something. If we give what we've got before we're ready, we're not thinking it through enough. If we say "you'll have to wait until we're ready to talk about it", then we're just kicking the can. I feel like, sometimes, our accessibility puts us in a position where we simply can't possibly win. This answer is _already_ more than I was comfortable communicating, but I put what I had out there because that's what transparency [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] .. has come to mean. We're not by any means done, this wasn't really even ready for scrutiny, and .. you see what I'm getting at here? I don't yet _have_ all the data, but people are demanding a response, and I owe you an apology for doing my best to communicate? Meh.

Comment: I think what Tim's trying to do here is apply some *systems-level thinking* to all of these problems, @jpmc26. You've been part of all this for a long time; I'd wager you've probably seen the direction that both this and similar communities tend to take... So you know then that folks tend to not stay in tidy little boxes: they grow, they change, they regress, they move on; there is an emergent behavior to the group that differs from that of any individual. The metric is important: it tells you *something* is wrong with the system... But you must understand the system as a whole to fix it.

Answer (score 74):

> It seems like the only thing that would be important is that knowledge contained with the users grows at the same rate as new programming technologies.

Imagine a week-long conference, where a group of experts are going to present some knowledge. Let's say there are 300 topics that need to be covered. Now, 10 experts *could* each make 30 presentations, at 4+ presentations a day. Or you could have 100 experts that each make 3 presentations.

Which one is better *for the experts?* I'm fairly sure they'd prefer to only have to make 3 presentations rather than 30. I'm also fairly sure that they'd prefer to have time to visit the presentations of *others*.

Having more people around to spread the work out is a good thing. It makes the system more functional. Each user doesn't have to do as much work, and therefore can enjoy the process more.

Furthermore, having more people around ensures that the system remains functional in the event of loss. Consider the conference example. If you have 10 people each scheduled to give 30 presentations, and one of them has to call in sick, you just lost 10% of your presentations. But if it's 100 people, you only lose 1%.

More people creates a more robust system.

> The amount of new programmers per year grows much more than the new languages/technologies/common questions, what is so important about decreasing user attrition?

Because user attrition is *how sites die.*

Every user, no matter how long they spend on the site, eventually moves on. That is the way of things. Whether through simply not having enough time to keep up, deciding to spend their time on something else, or through actual death, current users will eventually become *former* users.

A site has a healthy ecosystem if it creates more long-time users than it loses. And that process requires having a regular influx of new users. For every 100 new one-and-done new users, you might get 1 to stick around for the long haul. And it is those users who become long-time users that are responsible for keeping the site around, for becoming part of the site's ecosystem.

A site that experiences a net-loss of long-time users is a site that is *dying*. Once the site gets below a critical mass of skilled participants, there simply won't be sufficient expertise to make the site functional and useful for people.

Which brings us to:

> even if 0 users join from now until August next year, do you feel the quality/usefulness of SO will plummet?

That all depends on where you look, doesn't it?

From a quick look at your profile, you spend most of your SO time in the Python tag, one of the more popular tags on the site. A year's worth of no new users (and therefore significant negative user growth) probably won't change much for that tag.

What about less rich tags? In some cases, there are maybe 3-4 people who keep those tags functional. If they go away, those tags stop being functional until someone else shows up to pick up the slack. And of course, with no new users ever becoming long-term users, there will be far fewer chances for replacements (only from existing users who pick up that technology).

Your statement is the equivalent of "well, we've got lots of money now. Why not quit our jobs and live off of our savings?" I hope you can see why that's not a fiscally *sustainable* long-term strategy. Nor is living paycheck-to-paycheck: only keeping around the bare minimum to keep the site running effectively. That is a terribly fragile existence, financially and for the site.

SO is where it is because it gained a *wealth* of skilled users. If there has been a determination that we're losing that wealth, then that's a problem that is best fixed ASAP.

If you're flying a plane that starts losing altitude, it's better to do something about it when you still at 30,000 feet than when you're at 300.

Comment: A sane and patient answer.

Comment: It really comes down to numbers then doesn't it? I made the argument, which you may have missed, that people are responded to in minutes, often seconds. In your analogy, that would be someone coming off the street to the conference, throwing a topic, and within seconds gets another lecture (whether good or bad). So it is not enough to throw around we "are living off savings". That same comment you quoted points out we have no facts to work with - are we in a deficit? And the entire premise of the question asks, what deficit should SO care about? How many people of the street? Lecturers?topics?

Comment: @kabanus: "*I made the argument, which you may have missed, that people are responded to in minutes, often seconds.*" And I made the argument that this "all depends on where you look". You post in one of the most prolific tags on the site. Not all tags are so blessed.

Comment: By the way, it's nice (pun intended) to see a long time veteran user stand up for etiquette and good behaviour. Some of us are plain rude, regardless of quality, but we have tools for that as well. I did not see this discussed, but veteran and new user rude are really different things. I  do not think they need to be handled the same way. (Off topic)

Comment: @kabanus: "*That same comment you quoted points out we have no facts to work with - are we in a deficit?*" Do you expect SO the company to lay out whatever data they have to us before making decisions for the betterment of their own company? If they're willing to have one of their employees come out and say "we have a user attrition problem", the way I see it, you can either choose to believe them or not. But if you're willing to disbelieve them without foundation, then that means you don't trust them. So why would you trust any evidence they would have presented?

Comment: Last remark - 0 users was of course an extreme. Duekling interpolated that as well. Of course it is not sustainable, I was just arguing that garnering experts needs to be at the rate of new technology creation, not new programmer creation. I do not have favorite tags. Note I answered question i n quite a few languages, but the newest page is usually full of Python. If I see an interesting question from a language I never saw I learn it and try to answer, sometimes with success. The point being, you need much fewer people to quickly answer a diverse amount if questions, even in our modern world

Comment: Missed your response - I do not dis/trust. I think my assumption they are trying to increase the user base is fair. My question is why? Is it really they equate a general in flux of new users with the saving/betterment of SO? If so, why? I think I offered good alternatives to consider - are they good? Those are my questions. I am not against anything, or a free-speech-be-rude-freedom fighter. I am appalled by some of the responses on SO, but that is irrelevant. Are the ideas presented in the question far fetched? What should, SO care about maximizing (in the long run), even if just for profit?

Comment: Your answer is the reason I am not answering. It is a real gem. I like the analogies used, especially the conference. I also do not think that money is a core factor here considering all the people who work at the company and their general mantra of making the internet a better place. Fundamentally, there were issues with new user retention, and it is getting attention.

Comment: The size of the audience at the conference matters too - few will care about 100 experts chatting amongst themselves somewhere, but add an audience of 100k and people will take notice.

Comment: @kabanus «it's nice (pun intended) to see a long time veteran user stand up for etiquette and good behaviour.» The implication here is not appreciated. Where exactly do you see long time veteran users standing up for being rude?

Comment: @JoshCaswell: "*Where exactly do you see long time veteran users standing up for being rude?*" I can't say I know what he's talking about specifically, but [there's this.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/178870)  The problem usually manifests itself through plausible deniability; if there's some way to interpret a comment as not being rude, then they'll defend it as being fine.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I did not single anyone out, and I do not wish to. Is it really necessary I link to something? It will be both subjective and controversial. Maybe it is better to say I think some of the type of comments some of the users are defending (not just veterans) seem to me rude.

Comment: Thanks Nicol Bolas, that was exactly  my line of thinking, some interpretations seemed iffy.

Comment: Uh, wow...I haven't read that fully yet, but yes, @NicolBolas, that's definitely a -- discouraging -- example of defending rudeness. Yikes.

Comment: Great answer in a simple format that doesn't read like business jargon.

Comment: "*A site has a healthy ecosystem if it creates more long-time users than it loses. And that process requires having a regular influx of new users.*" Still, maybe SO should focus more on the new-user-to-long-time-user conversion rate than on a high influx.

Comment: Then, the question could be, how do we increase the popularity of less popular tags. Developers like challenges, there could be a way of saying "come and join this tag". Or if someone post in one of these tags, we can ask them to join in the help out.

Comment: *"it is those users who become long-time users that are responsible for keeping the site around, for becoming part of the site's ecosystem."* -- And it's believed that SO will keep more of the best of them by policing of every word that comes out of their mouths for subtle indications of having the personality of a programmer. How was that assumption validated? One of the things we used to do on SO under the bad old rules was to warn folks against optimizing away any inefficiencies they hadn't measured, or without considering what the optimization may cost elsewhere.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: "*subtle indications of having the personality of a programmer*" Is [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373258/734069) the "personality of a programmer"? Because I know plenty of programmers who aren't like that. Similarly, I still have the ability to warn people off of premature optimization without being a jerk. Users are not being asked to leap a particularly high bar.

Comment: @NicolBolas Those aren't subtle.

Comment: It's like some users are posting just so you have good examples (of very bad) to show... I do not get how these are so rare on the site yet have become the face of SO. It's the defense of these that is making more headlines than the actual comments I think.

Answer (score 18):

- More questions (more money)

  If you want to be the go-to resource for just about every professional programmer in the world, you need as many questions as possible to make it more likely that any given question is already on the site. More users = more questions.
- Better users (more money)

  If people are rude to one another, that makes your experts not want to be here as much as the target of the rudeness doesn't want to be here.

  Eventually you'll just be left with the blind leading the blind, with some grumpy people trying to chase them off their lawn.
- Public perception (more money)

  If the general public views it as a toxic place, that makes it much less valuable in just about every way (advertisers, and shareholders, wouldn't want to be associated with it, nor would they want much to do with the users who come here).
- Money

  More users = more money.

  More money = more money.
- Some ideal vision of what Stack Overflow should be

  You mean like a thing that generates lots of money?

Can the site *survive* if growth stagnates / decreases for a few years?

Probably, but the longer that goes on, the bigger the problem will be, and you'll need to deal with it at some point.

Of course none of this is to say I actually agree with how they're going about all of this.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178870/discussion-on-answer-by-dukeling-why-is-it-important-for-corporate-so-to-maintai).

Answer (score 10):

I was intending to make this a comment on Tim answer, but discovered that it was applicable to the actual question.

I have a problem with the concept of "new user growth rate", for a simple line of questioning: what is the main motivator for people joining the site? Since the world is awash with questions, I would say that the main reason people have to join the site is to ask a question. Even without a query I would be hard pressed to find that the first actions people do upon joining the site is not ask a question.

But that's not my problem with the concept, but the implications of such reasoning. The problem with said concept is that due the nature of the Q&A model, the natural thing to see is actually a plateau of new questions (and possibly a slow down), which would translate to a plateau of new users. If 95% of the users of the site (not accounts) are finding their answers through google, as it was claimed by Shog, then the metric to measure the health of the site is misguiding. The user growth rate is important to SO, but for measuring poor health: people are not finding the answers they need.

I would claim that if SO wanted to measure health, it should measure new answerers growth rate. Also the answerers attrition rate. If those metrics are positive and near 0, then the site is healthy and it grows its value.

Comment: There's a "wikipedia" like cut-off for certain; a time comes when, barring new features, the _breadth_ of any given language or tool has been covered. At that point what you end up is getting mostly duplicates that essentially point out the dozens of ways it occurs to folks to search for essentially the same thing. But, this varies pretty significantly by tag. We do account  for it, but we're pretty far from reaching that plateau in most _major_ tags as far as we know, but we still kinda stink at identifying duplicates accurately and that's a big canary.