# Can humour play a part in comments, and are these comments so rude and unwelcoming? I just got a reminder to be nice

Tags: discussion, comments, welcoming, code-of-conduct

I just got flagged for being **rude** and **unwelcoming**. No dramas there though; I sometimes get a little pointy. Also I understand what Stack Overflow is trying to do in light of those [silly blog](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366665/does-stack-exchange-really-want-to-conflate-newbies-with-women-people-of-color) [posts](https://medium.com/@Aprilw/suffering-on-stack-overflow-c46414a34a52), [Twitter posts](https://twitter.com/search?q=from%3Aaprilwensel%20%22stack%20overflow%22%20OR%20stackoverflow), and other Reddit fanfare that were grilling Stack Overflow about being sexiest, racist, rude, elitist and unwelcoming (most of which I have never seen, or very rarely see).

So these were the comments that were flagged (as per the email).

> - For someone with 1422 rep, you have certainly asked a bad question. How did you get these points?
> - OMG my eyes... what am i looking at
> - We cant read minds, show teh codez
> - Its minimal question detail hour.
> - This is not the make a wish foundation, please see the help on how to ask a good question and i'm sure you'll get plenty of answers
> - Omg, its that time of the day when people flood the site to ask vague questions with no information at all, please read the
>     StackOverflow Help to learn how to ask a question

**Please note I will adjust my comments. This is a great site and I will try to play ball.**

I personally think, making a point with humour is a great way to purvey meaning and memorable ways to make a point (and can be innately welcoming). Now some people may not think these are funny. Yet making any joke seems flaggable and unwelcoming; I mean anyone can read anything the wrong way if they want.

Should I prefix my jokes with disclaimers like the following?

> We cant read minds, show teh codez (Disclaimer, said in jest in the
>   nicest possible way to make you feel welcome, cozey, and give you warm fuzzies)

Anyway, the question is, should I just ditch the humour, because it can be viewed as unwelcoming, should I use a disclaimer, or should it be the case if I can't add something constructive, mono-tonal, and eloquently impartial, then I shouldn't comment at all (even with the best intentions to better the site and direct an OP in the right direction)?

I mean, it's kind of hard to participate and constantly vet what you say (when no harm is ever intended, well rarely)... Thoughts?

**Edit**

When looking at them all at once, it seems like I am an unwelcoming bot with the sole purpose to destroy young code Jedis' hopes and dreams and crush their little spirits back into the stone-age. However, these span months, and actually all made in jest.

Just to be clear, I am not worried about modifying my behaviour, or the fact I got a warning.

Comment: not to excuse your wording but you appear to be watching c# tag and per my observations it is severely flooded with very poor questions hanging open. Of "big" language tags only python seems to be damaged worse than c#. Wonder if [SOCVR folks](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570) would be interested in helping here, eg by spending few days cleaning most egregiously poor questions from close queue filtered by particular tag, like [python](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/20700210?filter-tags=python) or [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/20702578?filter-tags=c%23)

Comment: Just downvote if posts are so bad. If it makes you feel better you can say your joke out loud and have a little giggle before closing the tab but there's literally nothing to be gained for anyone from posting those kind of comments. Maybe I just don't have a sense of humour but I also fail to see anything funny about any of those examples. All I see is sarcasm that adds nothing the existing close-reasons doesn't already contain.

Comment: Sorry I might have flagged the last comment. While I understand your perspective, I felt that what you said was unfair to the asker. A lot of people, particularly people who don't have English as their first language, wouldn't get the "funny" part and rather find it offensive. I probably wouldn't mind that comment if there is a disclaimer, but it would still be "No longer needed". I have come across some of your constructive and helpful comments in C# tag as well. So I get how you might feel. But I agree completely with @ivarni on this one: just downvote and move on.

Comment: ... I mean I would prefer if you could strip down the sarcasm and still provide the feedback. But that's easier said than done. I, myself, try to provide constructive feedback whenever possible. But more than half the time, I just downvote, close-vote and move on to the next one.

Comment: Don't apply humour to SO, please. At SO we don't like fun https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### If the only way for you not making that kind of comment is for you to ditch humor, I think you should ditch it.

Had encountered any of those comments I would have flagged them as unkind: Not only the "humor" in them is at the expense of the asker, they do not provide any real, actionable help at all.

Comments like these have no upside: they may hurt the another user but not really help the user to improve their question, which is the point of comments. Not to *educate* the user to write better posts in the future, but to improve the post they are posted under, directly or indirectly, or to help to other users to provide better answers to the question.

As such, it is better to avoid these comments altogether. Even if you take out the humor they have, such as it is, you are left with a comment that provides no benefit.

If you want to be funny, try to do so without making jokes at the expense of other people. Make fun of yourself, for example. Many of the great comics have success doing so. Or you could say funny things about [the things we work with](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/coding-explained-in-25-profound-comics-8847ea03819c). Funny things about other people? Not so funny.

There is a regular in meta that very often attempts to make jokes at the expense of the language I mostly make my living upon. I do not find them funny (not because they are about something I use professionally, simply because I do not think that these are great, or even good jokes).

But I do not find them flaggable. They are not attempting to hurt anyone, hopefully, and the impersonal nature of the joke allows us to live in relative harmony, without having to ditch humor altogether.

You’ve only received a warning. You can adjust and carry on; which I think is great outcome. And for the record, I think the way you asked for community input and are reacting to the warning is very good. Kudos to you.