# Change of the new user attrition rate year over year

Tags: discussion, new-users, statistics, user-experience

The high new user attrition rate was mentioned a year ago as one of the reasons to introduce a code of conduct, new contributor labels or the question wizard.

With the high number of new users it should be possible to detect changes in this rate quite reliably.

Using the calculation of the new user attrition rate that the company used (which may be more accurate than what the public data sources can give), has the rate gone down significantly? Was there a delay? Or has there been so far no change?

Just curious. Looking for official answers.

<sub>P.S. Old user attrition rate would also be interesting. Has it changed compared to last year? If yes, in what direction and how much? How does it compare to the new user attrition rate (probably much lower)?</sub>

Comment: I mean, has anything changed that would affect it? A few blog posts have been made, but otherwise the public QA has gone mostly unchanged as far as i'm aware, other than the "new contributor" notice.

Comment: While moderators have access to this information, we're forbidden from sharing it without CM approval. I feel like this should be on meta.stackexchange.com since it's only a question that SE staff can answer.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I only want to know the values for StackOverflow, but if you think meta.stackexchange is the better place, I'm fine with that too.

Comment: @Trilarion I get it; that's why I haven't migrated it.  I want you to know that the only people who can give you an answer are the staff. :-/

Comment: @KevinB There was the code of conduct and I think that flaging of comments got a bit easier.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Can you migrate it?

Comment: @george This is just about SO, so I don't see a reason for migration?

Comment: @kevinB the 3 vote close vote experiment is probably the best thing done so far to make SO more friendly :)

Comment: @JonasWilms eh, maybe, but there's hardly been enough time to determine how that might have affected new user attrition rates

Comment: @KevinB The 3 vote close experiment just closes more questions. Not sure how this should have directly lowered the new user attrition rate. I'm really looking for a change compared to last year, maybe even without any visible change in the interface.

Comment: New users or new accounts?

Comment: A year ago the attrition rate was mentioned to be 30%-35%: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373227/16587 . If I understand your question you'd like to know if it's higher or lower now?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker That's really almost a year ago. Of course I would like to get as accurate numbers as possible, e.g. changed to X%, but qualitative descriptions like fell/rose lightly/strongly / stayed roughly the same would also be okay.

Comment: I think there might be a problem with assuming the reservoir of possible new users has the same characteristics of older new users. Attrition might be related to the length of time it takes to take the plunge in joining SO in the first place.

Comment: Going to get an answer to this, but it also involves putting in a data team request because the query path is just so huge and it has to be run against production. I'll comment again once I get an ETA from them (it might be a week or two because we've got so many experiments currently running).

Comment: @TimPost Very nice. For a moment I thought it would be 6-8 weeks. :)

Comment: @TimPost Reminder. Is an ETA available?

Comment: @TimPost it's a bit of time gone now. Is there still interest and maybe an ETA?

Comment: It looks like the mods attrition rate increased suddenly. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-slippery-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested