# Review Audit Failed - Why is my Eclipse not detecting java classes?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I failed this [review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/31174977)... and for the life of me I still can't see the issue.

> [image]

Comment: Do you know Java and understand the problem? I don't know Java but it looks like OP simply forgot to `import`, which really does sound like something that should be closed as typo/not reproducible

Comment: I do know Java...and it just seemed like a valid question.

Comment: Typo or not, the question is at least lacking a **complete** and reproducible example.

Comment: @BDL...thats sounds reasonable...

Answer (score 4):

It's a useless dupe at best. More practical to close it as a typo, since there are probably already a few thousand "you forgot your import statement" questions in different guises.

The question is incomplete, so "needs details" or "needs debugging details" would also fit as close reasons. But nevertheless, if it was complete, should be closed anyway.

Given all this, *"Looks Ok"* is certainly a wrong choice for this review.

Comment: The question has the debugging details.

Comment: No, it does not. If it did, it would have a complete snippet where we could see they are missing the import statement. Although again, even if we allow for the question not needing anything else, it's still closable as a dupe or a typo. "Looks ok" is still the wrong choice.

Comment: @ChrisCatignani - Even if that point was conceded the question is extremely low quality and a duplicate of a half dozen questions at a minimum. A single line of code, and an error statement, cannot make a question that can be answered beyond "you need an import statement" and revert back to the minimum statement on the reason it should be closed.  The reason you failed the audit is simple, the question was closed, but you didn't know that when you reviewed and indicated the question "looks Ok", so you said **a closed question** that was already handled properly **didn't need to be closed.**

Comment: @SecurityHound Look...I get it and see the evil on my ways. It was closed because it was "not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Well it is totally reproducible...leave off the Import.

Comment: @ChrisCatignani but then you are ignoring the "OR was caused by a typo" part. That is interesting research material, what a "typo" is.

Comment: @ChrisCatignani - So instead of saying the question "looks ok" you should have opened the question in another tab and voted to reopen it.  Likewise, there is another statement in that or statement, "caused by a typo" and leaving off an import in my opinion is a typo.  You can still vote to reopen that question by the way if you truly feel that question "looks ok" or you could have but it was deleted likely by the author due to the downvotes.

Comment: @SecurityHound it wasnt marked as closed to be able to reopen it.

Comment: @Gimpy there was no typo...just a missing Import.

Comment: @ChrisCatignani - Yes; That is the point of the audit.  In the future open the question in another tab.

Comment: @yivi "Color cannot be resolved to a type" is all the debuggin detail you need...plus there was a attached picture.

Comment: @SecurityHound...Ah...10-4

Comment: @ChrisCatignani An "attached picture" does not count. If code or error messages are present as images or links, it's as if they weren't present at all.

Comment: @yivi OK ... a piture doesnt count. But they listed the error...does that count?

Comment: Frankly, I fail to see the point of going on @Chris. The question was not "ok". It should have been closed, and had been correctly closed. A missing import is to be treated as a typo, same as a missing semi-colon, or a missing closing brace. At best, again, a dupe. But never "looks ok". Time to move on from this.

Comment: @yivi...agreed...thanks for your opinion.

Comment: @ChrisCatignani I think both sides of "typo" and "not reproducible" are missing the forest for the trees. Typos are *not* inherently off-topic. We have a lot of highly scored canonicals about simple to do mistakes like using `=` instead of `==`. The point of the close reason is, and I quote, "*While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers.*". The reason to choose this is because it's unlikely to help others. For example a typo of `MyFoo` vs `Myfoo` is not useful because other people won't have the same spelling mistake.

Comment: @ChrisCatignani We're not here to offer personalised debug experience for every single question asker. There isn't a checklist that says "If question has code and has error message then it's OK to post". We want *useful and high quality questions*. A trivial mistake that has been covered dozens of times is *not* a high quality question and is *not* something argue is OK. *At best* it's a good dupe flagpost. In which case it's still a dupe.

Comment: @VLAZ...I saw that it was the users first post...and thought it was a fairly decent first question for a new user. On the flip side of the coin...were not here to lambast the new users for what amounts to a mountain of "how to ask a question" errors.

Comment: @ChrisCatignani - First non-deleted question from a new user.  The author has asked similar low quality questions in the past.  The audit question has already been deleted by the community. Unclear if the question was deleted when you performed your audit but it's deleted now.

Comment: @SecurityHound The user has been on SO for 20 days and had asked only one other question (also dragged through the mud)...poor guy. If the powers at be expect a reviewer to: check if the question as been closed, check if the poster has a bad history of questions, check to see if it a duplicate..etc...etc. Its no wonder the ALL the ques are backed up. Im not venting here because of the audit...I was just really wondering the rational for this particular audit question. The best reason is that its a dupe...I didnt realize that part of the review process was to check for that...now I know.

Comment: @ChrisCatignani "*On the flip side of the coin...were not here to lambast the new users for what amounts to a mountain of "how to ask a question" errors*" correct. Please *do not moderate users*. That's not the job of SO. Moderate the content. You seem to be currently saying that the content is OK because it was posted by a new user. Does that mean that it wouldn't be OK if it was a different user? Or is that not actually related to the content at all? I'd say the last one.

Comment: @VLAZ "do not moderate users". So what it the reason behind the wavey hand that says "New Contributor". It means don't treat this person with the usual SO treatment. It begs to say that here is a user that may not know all the ins and outs to asking a question and to not hold them accountable for beginner mistakes we all make.

Comment: @ChrisCatignani "*So what it the reason behind the wavey hand that says "New Contributor".*" to signify you to take more care when you ask for clarification, commenting, and answering. These are not moderation actions. I've not seen anything official saying that the new contributor notification means "ignore quality standards when dealing with content from this user". Can you point to where you got your guidance from?

Comment: @vlaz https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373140/why-is-the-xxx-is-a-new-contributor-warning-reminded-in-the-answer-box You can interpret "bad user experience" anyway you want.

Comment: @ChrisCatignani the guidance there is *not*, as you try to claim, "waive the quality standards". Again, the goal is to maintain a high quality repository of solutions. Not to have a high quality repository of solutions but also some trivial duplicates. You're trying to assert the latter is acceptable based on who posted the content. It is not.

Comment: @ChrisCatignani if you have doubts about the significance of that message, feel free to do some research on meta and maybe post a new question if you feel there are things that should be cleared up. I don't feel discussing this under my answer is particularly constructive.

Comment: @yivi...I'm fine with it. Why didnt you direct your comments to VLAZ? ...I see...