# Add "please" to the Code of Conduct banner

Tags: discussion, new-contributor-indicator

There's a number of posts ([1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373140/why-is-the-xxx-is-a-new-contributor-warning-remi), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372877/new-contributor-indicator-can-we-make-it-less-intrusive), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314302/are-we-creating-divisions-in-our-quest-to-make-new-users-welcome/314519#314519), ...) discussing the necessity of the new [Code of Conduct banner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314287/come-take-a-look-at-our-new-contributor-indicator). While keeping in mind [Yvette Colomb's statement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373146/3995261) that those are targeted primarily to those "old" users who don't read meta, help and allow themselves being rude or not nice in another way (and the overall purpose of the banner that Yvette has described as well), I can't help asking: why the banners are not polite themselves?

I mean, now it reads

> ... is a new contributor. Be nice, and check out our Code of Conduct.

Shouldn't it be

> ... is a new contributor. Please be nice, and check out our Code of Conduct.

at least?

May be it also should mutate when the person has already visited the Code of Conduct page (why ask visiting it again? it's an annoying bit). If the link has to stay in the banner, the text can become

> ... is a new contributor. Please *be nice*

or something like that – where "be nice" is the link to the CoC (may be something encouraging should be added to the end of the phrase).

Comment: "code of conduct" to the "code of conduct"?

Comment: @Maroun it should be reflexive, right? :)

Comment: Deleted duplicate: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372934/no-you-be-nice

Comment: @user2285236 but that's not a list of rules, it's a call-to-action banner..

Comment: can we just stop indiscriminately pushing for fluff that pretends to look [meta-tag:welcoming] all over the system. Please

Comment: Being nice is not an option, there's no *please* to it...

Comment: @gnat I'm not sure whether you are referring to the banners themselves or to what I propose, but well, this proposition came from reading some comments complaining that the banner sounds somewhat rude

Comment: This might get a better response if you phrased the title as "Please add 'please' to the Code of Conduct banner". Eating your own dogfood and whatnot....

Comment: @RobertColumbia :D may be

Comment: Indeed, [it is impolite to order people around](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372934/no-you-be-nice), I thought. Apparently, not.

Comment: @WillNess unfortunately, I can't see the deleted question

Comment: @YakovL yeah, you need 10K rep for that. It just says what I quoted though, and has almost the same votes (N ups, 2N downs). But one of the entries you linked (thank you for that) explains the situation: they are worried about new users retention and slowing (or is it non-accelerating-enough?) growth. They know we are their captive user base. Whatever.

Answer (score -2):

I feel the same way but then I remember this site is about **seriousness and productivity** so being nice and polite is an option but not a norm as most users here are about productivity, **what is asked and what it needs to be fix** and that makes this site stand above others because of that, content is on point and clear. **Downvotes** and such can impact your experience but is part of the learning curve on how to ask and answer questions. Please take your time to read the Help Guide.